# await useAsyncData in setup doesn't block navigation in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I want to wait until navigating to the next page until the store data has been fetched and set.
I'm using Nuxt 3 + Supabase + Pinia

My approach in provider.vue (where user gets redirected after signing in/up to set cookies etc.)

```js
// redirect once user has been set
const user = useSupabaseUser()
watch(user, async () => {
    if (user.value) {
        await useSteps().handleNavigateToNextStep()
    }
}, { immediate: true })
```

`app.vue`: fetch store data. **I'm hoping to block navigation** by using await useAsyncData

```js
const user = useSupabaseUser()
await useAsyncData('userStoreData', async () => {
  if (user.value) {
    await useUserStore().fetchInitialData()
  }
}, { watch: [user] })
```

my store (reduced data for demonstration purpose)

```js
export const useUserStore = defineStore({
    id: 'UserStore',
    state: () => ({
        company: null as Tables<'company'> | null,
    }),
    actions: {
        async fetchInitialData() {
            const [companyData] = await Promise.all([
                useCompany().getCompany(),
            ])
            this.company = companyData;
        },
    }
})
```

... however, after the provider.vue redirects me, this value is undefined in one of my composables:
`const { company } = storeToRefs(useUserStore())`

How can I make the application wait until the store has been set?